# How to query data stored in Hive table using SparkSession of Spark2?

Tags: scala, maven, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to query data stored in Hive table from Spark2. Environment: 1.cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.7.0-0-vmware 2. Eclipse with Scala2.11.8 plugin  3. Spark2 and Maven under

I did not change spark default configuration. Do I need configure anything in Spark or Hive?

Code

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object hiveTest {
 def main (args: Array[String]){
   val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("HiveSQL")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

  val data=  sparkSession2.sql("select * from test.mark")
}
}
```

Getting error

```
16/08/29 00:18:10 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: select * from test.mark
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)
    at hiveTest$.main(hiveTest.scala:34)
    at hiveTest.main(hiveTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Duplicate SQLConfigEntry. spark.sql.hive.convertCTAS has been registered
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SQLConf$$register(SQLConf.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$SQLConfigBuilder$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$SQLConfigBuilder$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder$$anonfun$createWithDefault$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder$$anonfun$createWithDefault$1.apply(ConfigBuilder.scala:122)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.<init>(HiveUtils.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.<clinit>(HiveUtils.scala)
    ... 14 more
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Thanks
Robin

Comment: I'm surprised that the code compiles at all since you create `sparkSession` while using `sparkSession2`. I doubt the code is the one you execute. Could you explain the difference? How do you execute your application? What's your pom.xml (dependencies)?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object LoadCortexDataLake extends App {
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Cortex-Batch").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.read.parquet(file).createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
       spark.sql(s"insert overwrite table $table_nm partition(year='$yr',month='$mth',day='$dt') select * from temp")
```

I think you should use 'sparkSession.sql' instead of 'sparkSession2.sql'

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val spark = SparkSession.
  builder().
  appName("Connect to Hive").
  config("hive.metastore.warehouse.uris","thrift://cdh-hadoop-master:Port").
  enableHiveSupport().
  getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM  table_name")
```